# What happened to my new Block Region?

Tags: 7, theming

I've added a "header" block-region to the theme I am using (I am using the Visia Theme) and I've done this like so:

In my `visia.info` file:

```
regions[header] = Header
```

and in my `page.tpl.php` file:

```
<?php if ($page['header']): ?>
    <div class="header">
        <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This appeared to work, at first...

When I go to the `Blocks` page, the block region `header` does show up.

Also, when I click `Demonstrate Block Regions (visia)`, I see my block region, and its respected my CSS for it!

The issue is when I go to my actual webpage. The block isn't there at all! Even when I inspect the `Page Elements` in the developers console, I don't see anything for that block region, nor do I see any affects of the changes that I made to `page.tpl.php`!

And yes, I have "Cleared the Cache" many times...

Is there something I've missed?

Comment: Have you assigned any block in `Header` region?

Comment: And if you have assigned a block to that regions is it configured to show on the page you are viewing, and does the block have any content? If the block has no content (even say a views block where the view has no result or empty text) then it will not show and the header region won't show if it is empty.

Comment: also, are other changes that your making to your page.tpl.php file showing up?

Comment: I figured out the problem, and it made me feel dumb... Yes, I did assign a block to it, and it was showing up in my pages, but it wasn't showing up in my home page. Upon discovering this, I knew what the issue was. Along with the `Visia` theme comes a module called the `Page Builder`, which is actually quite cool, yet these pages are not constructed by the file `page.tpl.php`. Instead, the `Page Builder` page use their own file: `page--page-builder.tpl.php`. I had to make my changes here as well. That's all!

Comment: a detail blog: http://goo.gl/kD3TZu